# move constructors for vectors of shared_ptr<MyClass>

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, move, shared-ptr

I understand if you wish to pass a vector of MyClass objects and it is a temporary variable, if there is a move constructor defined for MyClass then this will be called, but what happens if you pass a vector of `boost::shared_ptr<MyClass>` or `std::shared_ptr<MyClass>`? Does the shared_ptr have a move constructor which then call's MyClass's move constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if there is a move constructor defined for MyClass then this will be called

Usually not. Moving a vector is usually done my transferring ownership of the managed array, leaving the moved-from vector empty. The objects themselves aren't touched. (I think there may be an exception if the two vectors have incompatible allocators, but that's beyond anything I've ever needed to deal with, so I'm not sure about the details there).

> Does the shared_ptr have a move constructor which then call's MyClass's move constructor?

No. Again, it has a move constructor which transfers ownership of the `MyClass` object to the new pointer, leaving the old pointer empty. The object itself is untouched.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `std::shared_ptr<T>` has a move constructor, as well as a templated constructor that can move from related shared pointers, but it does not touch the managed object at all. The newly constructed shared pointer shares ownership of the managed object (if there was one), and the moved-from pointer is disengaged ("null").

Example:

```
struct Base {};                // N.B.: No need for a virtual destructor
struct Derived : Base {};

auto p = std::make_shared<Derived>();
std::shared_ptr<Base> q = std::move(p);

assert(!p);
```

Comment: It has a regular move constructor as well as the template, since templates can't be used as move or copy constructors.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Reference?

Comment: C++11 20.7.2.2 for `shared_ptr`. More generally, 12.8/3: "A **non-template** constructor for class X is a move constructor if..."

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Thanks. I didn't see it in 20.7.2.2.1, but it's right there together with the templated version.

Comment: Isn't it UB, since Base has no virtual destructor? Why there is no need for it?

Comment: @BЈовић: Magic. There's a type-erased deleter that Does The Right Thing.

Comment: It is magic indeed :)  But is it working only for shared_ptr? I just tried with unique_ptr, and it didn't work. http://ideone.com/WfU5KO

Comment: @BЈовић: No, `unique_ptr` requires an explicit deleter, which you need to specify, and which is part of the type. In `shared_ptr` you're paying the price of type erasure for this magic.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean moving `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>>`. Then even the move constructor of `std::shared_ptr` won't be called. Because the move operation is directly done on `std::vector`level.

For example, a `std::vector<T>` may be implemented as a pointer to array of `T`, and a `size` member. The move constructor for this can be implemented as:

```
template <typename T>
class vector {
public:
    /* ... other members */
    vector(vector &&another): _p(another._p), _size(another._size) {
        /* Transfer data ownership */
        another._p = nullptr;
        another._size = 0;
    }

private:
    T *_p;
    size_t _size;
}
```

You can see in this process, no data member of type `T` is touched at all.

**EDIT**: More specially in C++11 Standard: **§23.2.1. General container requirements** (4) there is a table contains requirements on implementations of general containers, which contains following requirements:

(`X` is the type of the elements, `u` is an identifier declaration, `rv` is rvalue reference, `a` is a container of type `X`)

```
X u(rv)
X u = rv
```

C++ Standard: These two (move constructors) should have constant time complexity for all standard containers except `std::array`.

So it's easy to conclude implementations must use a way like I pointed above for move constructors of `std::vector` since it cannot invoke move constructors of individual elements or the time complexity will become linear time.

```
a = rv
```

C++ Standard: All existing elements of `a` are either move assigned to or destroyed a shall be equal to the value that `rv` had before this assignment.

This is for move assign operator. This sentence only states that original elements in `a` should be "properly handled" (either move-assigned in or destroyed). But this is not a strict requirement. IMHO implementations can choose the best suited way.

I also looked at code in Visual C++ 2013 and this is the snippet I found (`vector` header, starting from line 836):

```
/* Directly move, like code above */
void _Assign_rv(_Myt&& _Right, true_type)
{   // move from _Right, stealing its contents
    this->_Swap_all((_Myt&)_Right);
    this->_Myfirst = _Right._Myfirst;
    this->_Mylast = _Right._Mylast;
    this->_Myend = _Right._Myend;

    _Right._Myfirst = pointer();
    _Right._Mylast = pointer();
    _Right._Myend = pointer();
}

/* Both move assignment operator and move constructor will call this */
void _Assign_rv(_Myt&& _Right, false_type)
{    // move from _Right, possibly moving its contents
    if (get_allocator() == _Right.get_allocator())
        _Assign_rv(_STD forward<_Myt>(_Right), true_type());
    else
        _Construct(_STD make_move_iterator(_Right.begin()),
        _STD make_move_iterator(_Right.end()));
}
```

In this code the operation is clear: if both `this` and `right` operand have the same allocator, it will directly *steal* contents without doing anything on individual elements. But if they haven't, then move operations of individual elements will be called. At this time, other answers apply (for `std::shared_ptr` stuff).

Comment: I thought each element is moved too?

Comment: @user997112, I doubt so.